# How to hide 00:00 timespan using data string format in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, string-formatting

I have one column which contains value of type `TimeSpan`.

What I want to do show the empty cell if `TimeSpan` contains the `00:00` value else show as it is?

I tried doing various ways and didn't find any solution so thinking about using the jquery to accomplish this.

Before that wanted to know if it is possible using the `DataStringFormat`?

Comment: _"I tried doing varies ways"_ we're listening...

Comment: ya sorry for that i suck at english ........

Comment: I tried `various` `DataStringFormats` but didin't get it so thinking about using the jquery or converting the variable to the string type so i can set it to `string.empty` if value is `00:00` but before that thought ask here ....Any way thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `RowDataBound` instead:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int columnIndex = 0; // presuming the first column
        String tsText = e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Text;
        TimeSpan ts;
        if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(tsText, out ts) || ts == TimeSpan.Zero)
            e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Text = "";
        else
            e.Row.Cells[columnIndex].Text = ts.ToString();
    }
}
```